# How to get better random for array_rand in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random, php-7

is it possible to get better random (pseudo-random) for the function array_rand in PHP.
Something like random_int (added in PHP 7)

Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php is usually suffient or https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array_rand` return one *random* key of the array, *by default*. This function uses the [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html). If you need just one *random* value of the array you can use the `random_int`.

For example:

```
// One array:
$array = [0 => 'aaa', 100 => 'bbb', 'c' => 'ccc'];

// Force numeric key (now will be [0 => 'aaa', 1 => 'bbb', 2 => 'ccc']):
$array = array_values($array);

// Get one number between 0 and 2 (in this case):
$random_key = random_int(0, count($array) - 1);

echo $array[$random_key];
// Response: bbb
```

---

To be more easy to use you can use something like this:

```
function random_array(array $array) {

    $array = array_values($array);

    return $array[ random_int(0, count($array) - 1) ];

}
```

Only call:

```
$array = [0 => 'aaa', 100 => 'bbb', 'c' => 'ccc'];

echo random_array($array);
// Response: ccc
```

[**Test it!**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/176e6eef71b97c8104585d5a5b327353e128d4a3)

Comment: Yep. Done it the same way. Thank you, am sure it will help people!